# Strange segmentation fault in x86 assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, gdb

While I'm debugging a segmentation fault in x86-Linux, I've ran into this problem:

Here goes the seg-fault message from the GDB

```
0xe2a5a99f in my_function (pSt=pSt@entry=0xe1d09000, version=43)
```

Here goes the faulting assembly:

```
0xe2a5a994 <my_function>      push   %ebp
0xe2a5a995 <my_function+1>    push   %edi
0xe2a5a996 <my_function+2>    push   %esi
0xe2a5a997 <my_function+3>    push   %ebx
0xe2a5a998 <my_function+4>    lea    -0x100b0c(%esp),%esp
0xe2a5a99f <my_function+11>   call   0xe29966cb <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
0xe2a5a9a4 <my_function+16>   add    $0x9542c,%ebx
```

As you can see above, the faulting line is "call get_pc_thunk" which is just getting the pc value.
And, I checked the memory at 0xe29966cb is valid and accessible with the following command:

```
(gdb) x/10i 0xe29966cb
   0xe29966cb <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>:  nop
   0xe29966cc <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+1>:        nop
   0xe29966cd <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+2>:        nop
   0xe29966ce <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+3>:        nop
   0xe29966cf <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+4>:        nop
   0xe29966d0 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+5>:        nop
   0xe29966d1 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+6>:        nop
   0xe29966d2 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+7>:        nop
   0xe29966d3 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+8>:        mov    (%esp),%ebx
   0xe29966d6 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+11>:       ret
```

Which looks perfectly fine.
But Strangely, if I use "si" to step into the "get_pc_thunk" function, it seg-faults without even entering the first nop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what are the permissions on the segment at 0xe29966cb?

Comment: It is executable. get_pc_thunk is called by the previous function without any trouble.

Comment: Check the stack pointer, `call` wants to push the return address and maybe you have run out of stack space. In fact, the preceding instruction subtracts a big number from `esp` so that's very likely the problem.

Comment: To see if what @Jester suggests is true, try pushing something onto the stack just before you call get_pc_thunk. If it's true, then the push will segfault.

Comment: Yes right. It is seg-faulting on push. If I try to push after lea it gives seg-fault. My question is that why lea is subtracting so big number at the first place? Is it some kind of GCC error? And, How can I avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: You haven't showed C source, so we can only guess that you declared a local variable that's bigger than the available stack. You should allocate it from the heap instead.

Comment: Subtracting from esp is usually a way of allocating memory on the stack. The lea instruction allocates around 1Mb of memory on the stack, perhaps something like `int *big_array[1051404];`. That kind of memory should be allocated dynamically, using `malloc` or something.

Comment: In the reference before the call, `-0x100b0c(%esp)`, `-0x100b0c` looks like a pretty large offset. Are you sure you have rights to access that memory? Is this from a C/ function or did you write the assembly directly? The fact that it's referenced off of the stack pointer (`%esp`) and not the base pointer (`%ebp`) seems odd. Perhaps you can show what an earlier part of the assembly looks like, where it sets up the stack frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crash on `CALL` (or `PUSH`, of `MOV (%esp)`) instruction almost always is due to stack overflow.

Check your program for infinite (or just very deep) recursion.

Also, this:

```
0xe2a5a998 <my_function+4>    lea    -0x100b0c(%esp),%esp
```

means that `my_function` is allocating slightly over 1MB of local variables for the current stack frame. And now you know why that may not be a good idea.